# Updating with INSERT INTO on Conflict Error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

TWO QUESTIONS IN ONE:
Number one: This returns Failing row contains for name column and some more columns when trying to do it in SQL. However I know for a fact that the id allready exsist in the table. So how can I prevent it from giving this error?

Number two: The code returns error: syntax error at or near "$1" when ran in node? Is it beacuse values is a string and how can i prevent this?

This gives error *error: syntax error at or near "$1"*. I have a feeling

```
let values = ("("+req.body.oldid+","+false+"),("+req.body.newid+","+true+")")
    console.log(values) // returns (70,false),(4,true)
    const results = await db.query("INSERT INTO practiceSite (id,frontpage) VALUES $1 ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE frontpage = values(frontpage);",[values])
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to update 2 records at once? id 70 and id 4, is this correct? also, the $1 in the query will be replaced with your value (70,false),(4,true) as a string, which is why it's complaining. It's only expecting 1 of those.

Comment: What I am really tring to accomplish is that whan the Post is called I change the oldid to false in the database and the newid to true. I have column ID(BigSerial) and Frontpage(Boolean), I want to change the frontpage value for the specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, it looks like you'll only ever be inserting 2 entries at a time, so this should work.
In your example `values` is seen as a string, so we need to be more granular and pass in each parameter, and create the rows.

```
const results = await db.query(`
    INSERT INTO practiceSite (id, frontpage) 
    VALUES ($1, FALSE), ($2, TRUE) 
    ON CONFLICT 
    DO UPDATE SET frontpage = EXCLUDED.frontpage;
  `, 
  [req.body.oldid, req.body.newid]
)
```

Comment: Didnt work, ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name. When testing with two values I know exists in psql it returns: null value in column "name" of relation "practiceSite" violates not-null constraint:
Failing row contains (70, null, null, null, null, null, f, null, null, null).
Is it not possible to update without inserting every value?

Comment: @SurfaceNowy Could you please share the table schema?